# react typescript: use "Object.freeze" (enum) as type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this "enum":

```
export const AuthEnum = Object.freeze({
      AUTHENTICATED: 1,
    UNAUTHENTICATED: 2,
    PENDING: 3
})
```

This would work but is kind of misleading:

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<number>(AuthEnum.PENDING);
```

This is what I would like to do, but which doesn't work:

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<AuthEnum>(AuthEnum.PENDING);
```

This doesn't work either:

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<typeof AuthEnum>(AuthEnum.PENDING);
```

Is it possible to somehow indicate that the type of the state is AuthEnum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `useState<AuthEnum>(AuthEnum.PENDING)` does not work because `AuthEnum` is a runtime value and it is used as a type. It might be allowed to use in this way only if `AuthEnum` would be an enum.

This `const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<typeof AuthEnum>(AuthEnum.PENDING);`  does not work because `typeof AuthEnum` is an object and you are passing a  `AuthEnum.PENDING` which is a number.

In fact, you want to use only values of `AuthEnum`. In order to do that, first of all you should use `as const` assertion to narrow the type of object values.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const FakeEnum = {
    AUTHENTICATED: 1,
    UNAUTHENTICATED: 2,
    PENDING: 3
} as const // immutability assertion

export const AuthEnum = Object.freeze(FakeEnum)

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

const App = () => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<Values<typeof AuthEnum>>(AuthEnum.PENDING);

    setIsAuthenticated(1) // ok
    setIsAuthenticated(2) // ok
    setIsAuthenticated(3) // ok
    setIsAuthenticated(4) // expected error

    return null
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NddlXN)

`Values` utility type return a union of all object values.

---

> What's the reason for having "as const" ?

Without `as const` `AuthEnum` becomes just:

```js
Readonly<{
    AUTHENTICATED: number;
    UNAUTHENTICATED: number;
    PENDING: number;
}>
```

Whereas with `as const` - all object values are strictly narrowed:

```js
Readonly<{
    readonly AUTHENTICATED: 1;
    readonly UNAUTHENTICATED: 2;
    readonly PENDING: 3;
}>
```

`as const` makes your object not only immutable but also narrows all value types.

This is the reason why author of the question is used immutable object instead of `enum`. Since you have only 3 properties : `1, 2, 3` why would you allow to call `setIsAuthenticated` function with any other arguments? It is clear that calling `setIsAuthenticated(1000)` is invalid and should be highlighted as an error.

Please see this example with regular `enum`:

```js
enum AuthEnum {
    AUTHENTICATED = 1,
    UNAUTHENTICATED = 2,
    PENDING = 3
}

const App = () => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<AuthEnum>(AuthEnum.PENDING);
    setIsAuthenticated(100) // no error, but should be

    return null
}
```

There is no error, but we would expect. This is because values of enum are not infered.

You can check my [article](https://catchts.com/safe-enums) about using `enums` is a safer way.

Comment: What's the reason for having "as const" when you input it into `Object.freeze` immediately afterwards? Can't you just have: 
https://gyazo.com/6ec4d6a04955a358092d7d7b55b50b64.png
What difference does it make?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen I have updated my answer. Code from your example does not trigger an error here `setIsAuthenticated(4)`